# basic password strength validator

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation, passwords

I am trying to create a form that detects whether a password is weak, medium or strong. This is determined by its length.

I am new and slightly confused about javascript, so I have started the script but am missing some parts. So far I have made a function called passwordStrength using a if statement

We have been working on a more complex form in class so I have been copying parts from that.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

this is my javascript and a link to my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/xes8p/

```
var password = document.querySelector ('#password'); 
var submit = document.querySelector ('#submit');

function displayError (fieldname, message) {
 var input_field = document.querySelector('#' + fieldname);
 var error_box = document.querySelector('#'+fieldname+'Message');
}

function hideError(fieldname){
 var input_field = document.querySelector('#'+fieldname);
 var error_box = document.querySelector('#'+fieldname+'Message');

}


function passwordStrength () {

 if(passwordStrength.value <= 4){
displayError('password', 'Weak');

 }else if(passwordStrength.value > 4 && 
passwordStrength.value  <= 6){
displayError('password', 'Medium');

}else if (passwordStrength.value <6){
displayError('password', 'Strong');
}

return passwordStrength;
```

}

Comment: a) you did not link to a fiddle; and b) by StackOverflow rules, you should write the code in the question itself (although linking to a fiddle *as an addition to that* is awesome).

Comment: Please see [my answer to Should I reject obviously poor passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/51080/39623), which starts off with "Is it worth it to even include a password strength estimator?
No, because it is too difficult to inform normal users that the 'strength' listed is an absolute maximum possible strength, and that their password may be trivially crackable by a skilled opponent...

A known-weak-password warning? Absolutely! If you can detect that a password is weak, then it's weak. You merely cannot possibly detect whether or not a password is strong..."

Answer (score 0):

If length is only what define you can do something like this:

//#region JS

```
function passwordStrength() {
    var weak = 6;
   // var medium = 9;
    var strong = 12;
   var message ="Your password is strong";

    var currentPasswordLength = $("#my-password-id").val().length;

    if (currentPasswordLength < weak) {
        message  = "Your password is weak");
    } else if (currentPasswordLength < strong) {
       message = "Your password is medium");
    } 
    $("#my-span-id").text(message );
}

//   $(document).ready(function(){
$("#my-password-id").keyup(passwordStrength);
// });
//#endregion JS

<!-- HTML REGION-->

<input id="my-password-id" type="password" required/>
<span  id="my-span-id"></span>

<!-- HTML ENDREGION-->
```

FIDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uet23/